# python list to dictionary with dates as keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary from this list using dates as keys and successive items as its value.

```
lst = ['Thu Apr 04', ' Weigh In', 'Sat Apr 06', ' Collect NIC', ' Finish PTI Video', 'Wed Apr 10', ' Serum uric acid test', 'Sat Apr 13', ' 1:00pm', 'Get flag from dhariwal', 'Sun Apr 14', ' Louis CK Oh My God', ' 4:00pm', 'UPS Guy']

dict = {}

for item in lst:
    if item.startswith(('Mon','Tue','____Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'__))__:
        dict[item] = []
        saveItem = item
    else:
        dict[saveItem].append(item.____strip())
```

Keeps giving me syntax error.

P.S. not my code

Comment: looks like there are some strange underscores `____` in your code.

Comment: Agreed, remove all the underscores and it should work.

Comment: if i remove the underscores, the dates in the dict appear out of order {'Thu Apr 04': ['Weigh In'], 'Sat Apr 06': ['Collect NIC', 'Finish PTI
Video'], 'Wed Apr 10': ['Serum uric acid test'], 'Sun Apr 14':
['Louis CK Oh My God', '4:00pm', 'UPS Guy'], 'Sat Apr 13':
['1:00pm', 'Get flag from dhariwal']}
is there a way to populate the dict w/o losing order?

Comment: That's because dictionaries don't have an order. You probably want an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Could you post a working example?

Comment: @koogee There are examples in the documentation - they work exactly as normal dictionaries, just with order.

Comment: I don't think OrderedDict solves my issue. The keys are being inserted in the wrong order in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools as IT

items = ['Thu Apr 04', ' Weigh In', 'Sat Apr 06', ' Collect NIC', ' Finish PTI Video', 'Wed Apr 10', ' Serum uric acid test', 'Sat Apr 13', ' 1:00pm', 'Get flag from dhariwal', 'Sun Apr 14', ' Louis CK Oh My God', ' 4:00pm', 'UPS Guy']

date_word = ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')

def isdate(datestring):
    return any(datestring.startswith(d) for d in date_word)

items = (item.strip() for item in items)

data = (list(group) for key, group in IT.groupby(items, key=isdate))
for date, items in IT.izip(*[data]*2):
    print('{d} {i}'.format(d=date[0], i=items))
```

yields

```
Thu Apr 04 ['Weigh In']
Sat Apr 06 ['Collect NIC', 'Finish PTI Video']
Wed Apr 10 ['Serum uric acid test']
Sat Apr 13 ['1:00pm', 'Get flag from dhariwal']
Sun Apr 14 ['Louis CK Oh My God', '4:00pm', 'UPS Guy']
```

---

- You could use [IT.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the items as desired.
- If you don't don't dump the items into a dict, you can preserve the order in which the items appear.
- You can use the `zip(*[iterator]*2)` [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to group items in pairs.
- Avoid using variable names like `dict` since they shadow the Python builtin
  object of the same name.

Comment: As you can see the dictionary has no order in terms of date. How to generate an ordered dict with dates as keys and agenda items as values?

Comment: @koogee By definition, dictionaries don't maintain value.

Comment: the 'Wed Apr 10' key should have ['Finish PTI Video','4:00pm','UPS Guy'] as its value.

Comment: @koogee: Why associate `4:00pm` and `UPS Guy` with `Wed Apr 10`, when they follow `Sun Apr 14`?

Comment: sorry my mistake... but can they be stored like this instead of datetime objs w/o losing the order {'Thu Apr 04': ['Weigh In'], 'Sat Apr 06': ['Collect NIC', 'Finish PTI Video'], 'Wed Apr 10': ['Serum uric acid test'], 'Sat Apr 13': ['1:00pm', 'Get flag from dhariwal'], 'Sun Apr 14': ['Louis CK Oh My God', '4:00pm', 'UPS Guy']}

Comment: The keys in Python `dicts` have no inherent order. So the short answer is No. We can build the dict you are looking for, but to sort the keys in the dict, you'd have to define some function which maps keys to some orderable quantity. `dateutil.parser.parse` is such a function. It maps the keys to datetime.datetime objects, which are orderable.

Comment: i just need that date string for output. i don't care about how they're stored.

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question. The question states, "I'm trying to create a dictionary...". Naturally, we've been trying to create that dict. If you don't really care about the dict, and only care about the output, you have to tell us what output you really want.

Comment: thankyou. thats what i wanted.

Comment: @unutbu  Unrelated but what do you import `itertools` as `IT` I can understand lowercase `it` but uppercase `IT` is just confusing and inconsistent.

Comment: @jamylak: It is very common for people to `import lxml.etree as ET`, so there is precedence for using caps for module nicknames. I don't like using lowercase `it` as a module nickname because some people use `it` as a variable name for an iterable and if I copy their code into my code, I suddenly break my code. :) So I use caps so it never (hopefully) conflicts with a variable name.